# Highcharts: How to align text label middle center of pie chart

Tags: highcharts

I edit the codepen.io by thomas_rz

https://codepen.io/thomas_rz/pen/vXyoaK?editors=1010

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie',
      renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      floating: true,
      text: 'CENTERED<br>TEXT'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        innerSize: '50%',
        dataLabels: {
          align: 'right',
          distance: 10,
          connectorWidth: 0
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [
        ['Firefox', 44.2],
        ['IE7', 26.6],
        ['IE6', 20],
        ['Chrome', 3.1],
        ['Other', 5.4]
      ]
    }]
  });
});
```

and return this chart.

[image]

But i need this chart, text align middle center of pie

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data labels alignment explanation:**

Pie’s data labels doesn’t support that kind of look by default.

In Highcharts the position of a data label is strongly related to the position of its connector. You disabled connectors in your demo and that’s the reason why these labels look misplaced.

The algorithms always make sure that the center of label’s **VERTICAL** edge (label is perceived as a box) touches the end of connector. Your requirement is that connector should be able to touch **ANY** part of label’s box (vertical or horizontal):

[image]

It cannot be achieved without advanced Highcharts core modification.

**Workaround:**

I was able to implement something pretty close to what you need by redefining two core functions:

```
(function(H) {
  H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.dataLabelPositioners.radialDistributionX = function(series, point) {
    return point.labelPosition.natural.x - (point.half ? -0.5 : 0.5) * point.dataLabel.width;
  }
  H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.dataLabelPositioners.radialDistributionY = function(point) {
    return point.labelPosition.natural.y;
  }
})(Highcharts);
```

**Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/htk40ena/

The above code forces Highcharts to change the place where connectors touch labels. Please notice that connectors don’t make sense in my demo (try enabling them).

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts in calculations does not take into account the correct title height with `<br>` tag. You can calculate the right position of the title in the `render` event:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var title = this.title;
            title.attr({
                y: this.plotTop + this.plotHeight / 2 +
                    title.getBBox().height / 2 -
                    parseInt(title.styles.fontSize)
            });
        }
    }
},
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vnsp1ybz/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, but 'Chrome' and 'others' are still misaligned (off the axis of the slice).

Answer (score 1):

```
chart: {
      ...
        
      events: {
        render: function() {
          var title = this.title;
          renderTo: 'highcharts-container',
          title.attr({
            y: this.plotTop + (this.series[0].center[1])
          });
        }
      }
    },            
    title: {
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        floating: true,
        text: "CENTERED TEXT",
        useHTML: true,
      style: {
        "fontSize": "14px",
        "whiteSpace": "normal",
        "textAlign": "center",
        "color": "#fff"
      }
    }...
```